# Problems choosing directories with awt FileDialog

Tags: java, awt

I am a little bit confused. I changed back from the `JFileChooser` to the `awt.FileDialog` because my Customer wants the native look on Windows AND on OSX.

Now I have to configure the dialog that way, that the user can only open a directory not files. This is absolutely no problem with OSX because I only have to set the property

```
System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "true");
```

But for Windows I cant find any solution. What I can find is to set a `FilenameFilter`

```
class FolderFilter implements FilenameFilter
{
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
    {
        return new File(dir,name).isDirectory();
    }
}

FileDialog chooser = new FileDialog(this);
chooser.setFilenameFilter(new FolderFilter());
chooser.setMode(FileDialog.LOAD);
chooser.setVisible(true);
String folderSelected = chooser.getDirectory();
```

But this has absolutely no affect. When I select a folder and press the "open" Button it still enters the directory instead of closing the Dialog and give the folder back.

What am I missing?

Comment: *"I changed back from the `JFileChooser` to the `awt.FileDialog` because my Customer wants the native look on Windows AND on OSX."* Give them `JFileChooser` with the native PLAF..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you're not doing anything wrong. That is the expected FileDialog behavior.

Here is what you can do:

1. Revert back to Swing's JFileChooser. If you use the default system look & feel, they will look native.
2. Use [JavaFX's DirectoryChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html).
3. Use a third party library, like [L2FProd's Common Components](http://www.l2fprod.com/common/), which feature a JDirectoryChooser.